# What happens to reputation used for a bounty that was never awarded to another user?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, unanswered-questions

Edit: I need to apologise for this.. I was having a particularly bad week in a string of crappy ones; long story short, I vented in the wrong way at the wrong people. For that I am so very sorry.

---

So my first experience using the bounty system on SO appears to have resulted in nothing more than me losing half my rep, with no way to recover anything.

I asked a question, which didn't get much attention at all, I added a bounty in the hopes that it might help, and then just as the bounty was ending I worked out the answer to my question and updated it as such.

While the bounty was active, one other user posted an answer with a question because they didn't have enough rep for a comment. They deleted their answer after this and nobody else added any answers.

After the bounty had expired, I added an answer explaining my software issue was caused by an unknown hardware error and marked that as the correct answer.

Now I'm down 400 rotation points (at that point it was more than half of what I had) and there doesn't seem to be anything I can do. Is this now just gone, or is there anything that can be done to restore this?

Suffice to say this is the last time I will ever try use the bounty system; if one of my questions doesn't get enough attention I'll just rephrase it and hope for the best... The concept of losing reputation without it being assigned to anyone else is just plain stupid, simple as that.

There should be a warning before the bounty is enabled to state that it will be immediately and permanently removed from the current users reputation points. I saw no such warning when I used it myself.

Comment: Multi-dup:  'if you pay $XXXXX for TV adverts, and sales revenue does not improve, can you get your money back from the TV company?', (NO - they will simply say that your produce was no good and so, despite their best efforts, nobody wanted it).

Comment: If that is the case, there should be a warning before the bounty is enabled to state that it will be immediately and permanently removed from the current users reputation points. I saw no such warning when I used it myself.

Comment: Here's another approach: if legal department offers a bounty for retrieving something, are they still forced to pay it out if their requested item is never retrieved? THAT is a bounty in my mind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty: 'All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances'

Comment: Did this seriously deserve a downvote? For what, because someone else's question with completely different wording didn't show up below the input when I typed my question? Seriously?

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get more rotation points in the future.  In fact, there are four rotation points on the earth, midnight, mid day, sunrise and sunset.  Each Time corner point rotates through the other 3-corner Time points, thus creating 16 corners, 96 hours and 4-simultaneous 24-hour Days within a single rotation of Earth.  That means you'll get all your rotation points back in approximately 100 days.

Comment: @Won't, that's pretty creative, thanks for the laugh.. I think I needed that after the day I've had. (:

Comment: You can't just change the question into something else. If you want, you can flag the question and ask to dis-associate it from your account. Otherwise, leave it alone.

Comment: My point is that it isn't a question anyway, but whatever, I'm done with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounty [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and bounty dialog are very clear:

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances

And:

> (this reputation is deducted immediately and cannot be refunded)
>
> [image: dialog]

So no. You can't get it back, under no circumstances. You paid for your ad, and now your money is gone. Both statements are unambiguous, so no need to change them, as you suggest.